# Error while creating name manager

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, excel-formula

I have an Excel file which has a column formatted as date in the format dd-mm-YYYY.

I need to convert that field to text. If I change the field type excel converts it to a strange value (like 40603).

I tried the text function but it gives me Error 508.

i learn this method in http://www.excel-formulas.in/2016/01/names-in-excel-formulas-online.html

Any help?

Comment: "text function but it gives me Error 508". Truly in Excel? Sounds like Openoffice or Libreoffice Calc. https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc_Error_Codes

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this would relate to the name range manager, anyway...select the cell that you want the string to be placed in and use the following formula

```
=TEXT(A1,"dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
```

You can edit how you want the date to be displayed inside the quotes

```
dddd = Monday, Tuesday...
ddd = Mon, Tue...
dd = 01, 02...
d = 1, 2...

mmmmm = J, F...
mmmm = January, February...
mmm = Jan, Feb...
mm = 01, 02...
m = 1, 2...

yyyy = 2016, 2017...
yy = 16, 17...
```

Hope this helps